How to prevent partition-only differences in QAT output?
I'm using this pattern on QAT:

AC;DEF;~F~E;~D~C~A;!=AC;!=CD;!=DE;|A|=1-6;|C|=1-6;|AC|=7-;|EF|=4-

to find word pairs that can be reversed and have space moved to make new words. Like

degauss aesop > pose assuaged

(note, these aren't just anagrams of eachother)
But when QAT renders its results, because of how I've constructed the pattern it gives all partitions of a word until it times out:

d·egauss
de·gauss
deg·auss
dega·uss
degau·ss

Is there a way to prevent this?

Try this site

Maybe https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=A%3BDE%3B%7EE%3B%7ED%7EA%3B%7CA%7C%3D7-%3B%7CE%7C%3D4-&ent=Search&dict=0 ?

@tToE that's just anagrams though, which is now what I'm after

@msh210 that works! I'm not sure what I was anticipating, or remembering from previous issues that made this a bigger problem than it was.

The pattern A;DE;~E;~D~A;|A|=7-;|E|=4- should work for you.
